# Not enough emphasis on some symbols

Tags: fonts, listings, fontsize, emphasis

I'm trying to write some text in bold font but some symbols are not set in bold properly. The emphasis is set with `\bfseries` and is correct for :: and = but not enough for > and -.
See below image for details.

[image: Example]

I'm working in a lstlisting environment in beamer but in normal latex environment I have the same result.

Is there a way to have the same emphasis on these symbols? A specific font or package to load?

Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[containsverbatim]
\frametitle{Zip}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=haskell,basicstyle=\bfseries]
zip :: [a] :: => -> [b] -> [(a, b)]  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Please post a complete, *minimal* document with the relevant settings and illustrating the problem.

Comment: [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\boldsymbol`; compare `$\boldsymbol{:-=>}$` to `$:-=>$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listings is using math mode for some characters so you can add `\boldmath` to the style, but then still in OT1 with cm fonts substitutions make some characters non bold, here I use T1 latin modern which gets a slightly more consistent look:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\begin{frame}[containsverbatim]
\frametitle{Zip}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=haskell,basicstyle=\bfseries\boldmath]
zip :: [a] :: => -> [b] -> [(a, b)]  
\end{lstlisting}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```